# How to convert a strig value like (a/b) to a float value?

Tags: python

i have the next code

```
Constx = (float(input("constant of X?")))
```

I want to input division values like 1/2, 3/4, etc. but i have the next error message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1/2'
```

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate the expression first before:

```
Constx = (float(eval(input("constant of X?"))))
```

**WARNING** This is very vulnerable !! Any statement you enter in the prompt will be executed !!

Comment: I entered `os.system("rm -rf /")` and now I can't boot my system. Vulnerable, indeed :-) Using `eval` should generally *never* be allowed on arbitrary input.

Comment: @paxdiablo appreciate your bravery

Comment: Well, to be honest, I didn't *actually* enter that, since I know the chaos it would cause (and, in any case, I'm currently sitting at a Windows box). There's a very thin line between bravery and stupidity :-)

Comment: Yes i know that you didn't do that but execution of that will just screw the system

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved through a number of ways, but one simple method is to use [eval:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

> The return value is the result of the evaluated expression. Syntax errors are reported as exceptions.

This means that `eval()`will evaluate the value of the string expression that it is given, and return either an integer or float depending on the expression (it can actually return a large number of different outputs, but in this case it would likely only be an int or float). An implementation of this may look like:

```
Constx = eval(input('constant of X?'))
```

As a note, `eval()` is generally considered to be unsafe for any arbitrary input, because it can evaluate much more than basic arithmetic, such as other python statements. However in this circumstance, you likely don't need to worry about using anything more than this.

If you do intend on creating more universal code, then you may consider using a library that mimics `eval()` in a safe way. I am not experienced enough to offer a definitive "best" eval-like library, but I do know that [simpleeval](https://pypi.org/project/simpleeval/) and [pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing) are decent alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the need to post a solution which does not depend on `eval`.  As other answers have pointed out, `eval` can be very dangerous when fed raw input.  Here is a solution which does not depend on `eval`, and depends on no external libraries. It is true that `regex` would have saved a few lines of code.

The version is designed also to handle a whole number part as well.  `1 1/2`, `1/2`, or  `0 2/3`.  It will pass the `ValueError` up the chain for the caller to address if the string contains elements that do not fit the pattern; else it returns a `float`.

```
def frac_to_float(st):
    f = 0.00
    elements = st.split(' ')
    for e in elements:
        if '/' in e:
            n, d = map(float, e.split('/'))
            f += n/d
        else:
            f += float(e)
    return f
```